# GAE leaving mysql connections open

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Some times happens that the GAE App engine instance is failing to respond successfully, for requests that apparently do not cause exceptions in the Django app.

Then I check the processlist in MySQL instance and see that there are many unnecessary processes open by localhost, and probably the server app is trying to open a new connection and hits the process limit.

Why is the server creating new processes but fails to close the connections at the end? How to close these connections programatically?

If I restart the App engine instance the 500 errors (and mysql threads) disappear.

```
| 7422 | root          | localhost    | prova2 | Sleep   |  1278 |             | NULL
| 7436 | root          | localhost    | prova2 | Sleep   |   703 |             | NULL
| 7440 | root          | localhost    | prova2 | Sleep   |   699 |             | NUL
| 7442 | root          | localhost    | prova2 | Sleep   |   697 |             | NULL
| 7446 | root          | localhost    | prova2 | Sleep   |   694 |             | NULL
| 7448 | root          | localhost    | prova2 | Sleep   |   694 |             | NULL
| 7450 | root          | localhost    | prova2 | Sleep   |   693 |             | NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problematic code was middleware that stores the queries and produces some summary data of requests.  The problem of sleeping connections disappears when I remove this section in appengine_config.py:

```
def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):
    from google.appengine.ext.appstats import recording
    app = recording.appstats_wsgi_middleware(app)
    return app
```